# issues installing with apt-get on fresh install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, installation, apt

Fresh server install of 12.04 ubuntu 64BIT. Any ideas as to why this is not working?

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get install kvm libvirt-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
bridge-utils cgroup-lite cpu-checker dnsmasq-base ebtables gawk kvm-ipxe
libaio1 libapparmor1 libasound2 libasyncns0 libavahi-client3
libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcaca0 libflac8 libjson0
libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnspr4 libnss3 libnuma1 libogg0 libpulse0
librados2 librbd1 libsdl1.2debian libsigsegv2 libsndfile1 libvirt0
libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libxenstore3.0 libxml2-utils libyajl1 msr-tools
qemu-common qemu-kvm qemu-utils seabios vgabios
Suggested packages:
libasound2-plugins libasound2-python pulseaudio policykit-1 radvd lvm2
mol-drivers-macosx openbios-sparc ubuntu-vm-builder uml-utilities
The following NEW packages will be installed:
bridge-utils cgroup-lite cpu-checker dnsmasq-base ebtables gawk kvm kvm-ipxe
libaio1 libapparmor1 libasound2 libasyncns0 libavahi-client3
libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcaca0 libflac8 libjson0
libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnspr4 libnss3 libnuma1 libogg0 libpulse0
librados2 librbd1 libsdl1.2debian libsigsegv2 libsndfile1 libvirt-bin
libvirt0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libxenstore3.0 libxml2-utils libyajl1
msr-tools qemu-common qemu-kvm qemu-utils seabios vgabios
0 upgraded, 42 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 40.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main bridge-utils amd64 1.5-2ubuntu6
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libsigsegv2 amd64 2.9-4ubuntu2
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main gawk amd64 1:3.1.8+dfsg-0.1ubuntu1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libaio1 amd64 0.3.109-2ubuntu1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libasound2 amd64 1.0.25-1ubuntu10.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libasyncns0 amd64 0.8-4
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libavahi-common-data amd64 0.6.30-5ubuntu2
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libavahi-common3 amd64 0.6.30-5ubuntu2
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libavahi-client3 amd64 0.6.30-5ubuntu2
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libcaca0 amd64 0.99.beta17-2.1ubuntu2
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libogg0 amd64 1.2.2~dfsg-1ubuntu1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libflac8 amd64 1.2.1-6
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libnspr4 amd64 4.8.9-1ubuntu2.3
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libnss3 amd64 3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubuntu6
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libjson0 amd64 0.9-1ubuntu1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libvorbis0a amd64 1.3.2-1ubuntu3
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libvorbisenc2 amd64 1.3.2-1ubuntu3
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libsndfile1 amd64 1.0.25-4
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libpulse0 amd64 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libsdl1.2debian amd64 1.2.14-6.4ubuntu3
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main seabios all 0.6.2-0ubuntu2.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main vgabios all 0.6c-2ubuntu3
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main qemu-common all 1.0+noroms-0ubuntu14.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main librados2 amd64 0.41-1ubuntu2.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main librbd1 amd64 0.41-1ubuntu2.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main qemu-utils amd64 1.0+noroms-0ubuntu14.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main qemu-kvm amd64 1.0+noroms-0ubuntu14.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libyajl1 amd64 1.0.12-2
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main msr-tools amd64 1.2-3
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main cpu-checker amd64 0.7-0ubuntu1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libnetfilter-conntrack3 amd64 0.9.1-1ubuntu1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main dnsmasq-base amd64 2.59-4
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main ebtables amd64 2.0.9.2-2ubuntu2
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main kvm amd64 1:84+dfsg-0ubuntu16+1.0+noroms+0ubuntu14
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main kvm-ipxe all 1.0.0+git-3.55f6c88-0ubuntu1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libapparmor1 amd64 2.7.102-0ubuntu3.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libnuma1 amd64 2.0.8~rc3-1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libxenstore3.0 amd64 4.1.2-2ubuntu2.2
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libvirt0 amd64 0.9.8-2ubuntu17.3
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main cgroup-lite all 1.1.2
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libvirt-bin amd64 0.9.8-2ubuntu17.3
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main libxml2-utils amd64 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.1
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/b/bridge-utils/bridge-utils_1.5-2ubuntu6_a
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libs/libsigsegv/libsigsegv2_2.9-4ubuntu2_a
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/g/gawk/gawk_3.1.8+dfsg-0.1ubuntu1_amd64.de
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/liba/libaio/libaio1_0.3.109-2ubuntu1_amd64
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10.1_a
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/liba/libasyncns/libasyncns0_0.8-4_amd64.de
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-common-data_0.6.30-5ubunt
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-common3_0.6.30-5ubuntu2_a
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-client3_0.6.30-5ubuntu2_a
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libc/libcaca/libcaca0_0.99.beta17-2.1ubunt
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libo/libogg/libogg0_1.2.2~dfsg-1ubuntu1_am
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/f/flac/libflac8_1.2.1-6_amd64.deb Tempora
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/n/nspr/libnspr4_4.8.9-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.13.1.with.ckbi.1.88-1ubunt
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/j/json-c/libjson0_0.9-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libv/libvorbis/libvorbis0a_1.3.2-1ubuntu3_
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libv/libvorbis/libvorbisenc2_1.3.2-1ubuntu
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libs/libsndfile/libsndfile1_1.0.25-4_amd64
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/libpulse0_1.1-0ubuntu15.1_amd
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libs/libsdl1.2/libsdl1.2debian_1.2.14-6.4u
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/s/seabios/seabios_0.6.2-0ubunt
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/v/vgabios/vgabios_0.6c-2ubuntu
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/q/qemu-kvm/qemu-common_1.0+nor
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/c/ceph/librados2_0.41-1ubuntu2
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/c/ceph/librbd1_0.41-1ubuntu2.1
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/q/qemu-kvm/qemu-utils_1.0+noro
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/q/qemu-kvm/qemu-kvm_1.0+noroms
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/y/yajl/libyajl1_1.0.12-2_amd64
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/m/msr-tools/msr-tools_1.2-3_am
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/c/cpu-checker/cpu-checker_0.7-
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libn/libnetfilter-conntrack/li
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/d/dnsmasq/dnsmasq-base_2.59-4_
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/e/ebtables/ebtables_2.0.9.2-2u
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/q/qemu-kvm/kvm_84+dfsg-0ubuntu
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/i/ipxe/kvm-ipxe_1.0.0+git-3.55
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/a/apparmor/libapparmor1_2.7.10
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/n/numactl/libnuma1_2.0.8~rc3-1
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/x/xen/libxenstore3.0_4.1.2-2ub
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libv/libvirt/libvirt0_0.9.8-2u
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/c/cgroup-lite/cgroup-lite_1.1.
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libv/libvirt/libvirt-bin_0.9.8
Failed to fetch http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2-utils_2.7
```

My Sources file:

```
 deb http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise main restricted

# deb http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise-updates main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise universe
deb-src http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise universe
deb http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise multiverse
deb http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

EDIT:
Took advice below and I got this:

```
apt-get update
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Err http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/ precise/main bridge-utils amd64 1.5-2ubuntu6
Temporary failure resolving 'ubuntu-12.04.pxe'
```

Your configured Ubuntu archive can't be resolved. If you have an internal archive then make sure that it's working and you're using the correct hostname. If not, then edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" instead of "http://ubuntu-12.04.pxe/". Run `apt-get update` afterwards.

**Edit**: It looks like DNS is not working on your system at all. Check that you have the correct DNS servers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf` and that you can ping them.

Comment: Added my sources file. Do I need to replace ever instance?

Comment: @ThompsonSmith Only the ones you actually want to work :)

Comment: Not sure which ones I work with. Just was trying to isntall that stuff ;/